# CSS transitions: jumpy response

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I have an element scale its size upon hover but for some reason the animation is very jumpy when you move your mouse quickly / after you view the animation once.  I know there are a lot of similar questions but I am relatively new to CSS transitions and I have not found a solution that works.

[My Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qE9kJ/193)

You can ignore the jQuery but I included it incase it is responsible for the jumpy behavior.

### CSS

```
.circle-container {
    background-color: #FDA220;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin-top: -60px;

    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;

    &:hover {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.25); 
        -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
        -o-transform: scale(1.25);
        transform: scale(1.25);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works nice and smoothly for me in Chrome 46.0.2490.71 on a 2011 13" MacBook Pro / 10.10.5

Comment: try resizing the window and see if it still does

Comment: For me it works fine as long as you get rid of the jquery... then it won't be responsive but (juts my opinion) I think using css media queries for responsive behaviour will make your example works better and (again my opinion) easier to implement